# Transactional replication on SQL server without primary key

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We are implementing a snapshot replication on our current system 
Lately, the system require us to apply the "instant replication" (require the low latency between articles on Publisher and Subscriber)

Unfortunately, the tables on Publisher have not Primary key (but they have some unique index). The database on Publisher is not on our control, that means we are not allowed to change the schema of the database ( add primary key or add column)

I cannot use Transactional Replication (due to no-primary key problem) or Merge Replication (due to the fact that Merge Replication automatically adds Guid column on our tables)

I wonder if I have any way to resolve this problem ( we use Sql server 2012 Enterprise Edition on Publisher and Sql 2014 Web Edition on Subscriber)

Comment: are you doing this replication for reporting purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Implementing Replication without the primary keys leave you with the only option of Merge Replication.

As you correctly mentioned Merge replication will add a guid column to all the tables, unfortunately there is no way around to it unless you add a Dummy primary key column where primary is missing.

All in all if replication is the only option and you have missing Primary keys, Merge Replication is the only type of replication you can implement. Else look into other options like Log shipping or Mirroring.